# Finding app base for embedded tomcat in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using spring boot. I am developing a web application and i need to get the app base to generate a link for an email. For that i need to get the base URL. As the tomcat is embedded
`request.getContextpath()`
returns null. I need to get that `localhost:8080` dynamically so that when I deploy this to server I don't have to change the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a spring boot application you can change the server context in the application.properties with the properties server.context-path=your-path

in your code you can refer to this properties like below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    ServerProperties serverProperties;

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("serverProperties.getContextPath(): " + serverProperties.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

The key point here is use `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServerProperties.class)` on your `@Configuration` class and then use the injected fiels ServerProperties for consume the value.

I hope that this can help you...

Comment: A my advice is use relative url don't use a full qualifaid path because the your code will be too mutch tightly coupled with protocoll host and so on

Answer (score 0):

Huh, that took me some time to get there but:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext context = (AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext)SpringApplication.run(TestServiceApplication.class, args);
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer tomcatContainer = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer)context.getEmbeddedServletContainer();

    String host = tomcatContainer.getTomcat().getHost().getName();
    int port = tomcatContainer.getPort();

    System.out.println("Host:port " + host + ":" + port);

}
```

}

Output: `Host:port localhost:8080`

Is that what You wanted?